# Как отсортировать два списка по одному индексу

Tags: python

Чтобы было понятнее понять суть моего вопроса, скажу что я хочу сделать. У меня есть два файла, в первом хранятся артикул и цена товара, во втором хранятся мне нужные артикулы товара в меньшем количестве чем в первом. Мне нужно присвоить к артикулу второго файла цену из первого файла. Для этого я хочу использовать бинарный поиск

Вот пример бинарного поиска:

```
nums = [5,7,6,9,8,4,2,3,1]
nums.sort()
print(nums)

search = 7
print('Мы хотим найти: ', search)
lowest = 0
highest = len(nums) - 1
index = None

while(lowest <= highest) and (index is None):
    mid = (lowest+highest) // 2

    if nums[mid] == search:
        index = mid
    else:
        if search < nums[mid]:
            highest = mid - 1
        else:
            lowest = mid + 1

print('Искомый элемент: ', nums[index])
```

Вот мой скрипт:

```
import csv
import os
import xlrd

file_art = 'Артикулы всех товаров Aurora.csv'
file_quan = '2.xls'

def get_comparison(file_art, file_quan):
    product_all = []
    quantity = []
    price = []

    with open(file_art, "r") as file_obj:
        reader = csv.reader(file_obj)
        for row in reader:
            check = "".join(row)
            if check == 'Articul':
                pass
            else:
                product_all.append(int(check))
    product_all.sort()
    print(product_all)
    
    excel_data = xlrd.open_workbook('./' + file_quan)
    sheet = excel_data.sheet_by_index(0)
    row_number = sheet.nrows

    for row in range(1, row_number):
        quantity.append(int((str(sheet.row(row)[1]).replace('.0','').replace('number:',''))))
        price.append(str(sheet.row(row)[8]).replace('number:',''))
    quantity.sort()
    print(price)

get_comparison(file_art, file_quan)
```

Индекс элементов списков: `price, quantity`, соответствуют друг другу (То есть артикул списка `quantity` соответствуют цене в списке `price`), но когда я сортирую список `quantity`, у меня теряется соответствие индексов элементов цены и артикула в списках. Можно ли как нибудь присвоить идексацию `quantity`, к  `price`? Надеюсь понятно изложил, если не понятно, то задавайте вопросы))))

Comment: Тут надо менять всю систему. Создайте словарь, содержащий артикулы (как ключ) и цены, и поиск  будет мгновенный, и цена всегда при артикуле.

Comment: А отсортировать можно будет словарь по артикулам?

Comment: А словарь не надо сортировать, он индексируется полем-ключом, т.е. Dict[articul] сразу даст значение цены (при наличии артикула)

Comment: А при этом разве будет работать бинарный поиск? Ведь без сортировки артикулов она работать не будет

Comment: Почитайте, что такое словарь (dictionary, map). Бинарный поиск не потребуется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для каждой задачи надо искать наиболее адекватный инструмент ее решения.
И ваша задача -  это классическая (прямо -  учебная) задача на работу с DataFrame из Pandas.

Создаете два датафрейма вместо (можно из)  ваших таблиц. Потом выполняйте любые операции над ними -  в вашем случае - соединение двух фреймов по артикулу. В одну строчку  получаете ответ на ваш вопрос, как и на множество других, которые сможете придумать. Сортировки, подсчеты всяких сумм и пр. статистики - делается в один оператор, а иногда и проще.